# How to get the browser timezone and country name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the browser timezone (client's timezone) and country name when the client logins into the application in different countries in jQuery/JavaScript?

I tried many codes from google but I am getting server time instead of client's timezone. Please help me to get out of this..

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Comment: we are getting browser timezone,offset through Javascript, and i m sending these values to server(java),by using jstz library but in few cases i am unable to fetch timezone..please go thorugh  that library and test for Aleutian Islands. Please suggest a better solution that works for all all timezones.

Answer (score 3):

To get user timezone

```html
<script>
 alert(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mani. But there is no results for some timezones..like   when i am selecting "Aleutian Islands" i am getting the following  error:    "message": "Uncaught RangeError: Unsupported time zone specified undefined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 13
}

Answer (score 0):

You can get timezone by using moment.js and jstz.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.6/jstz.min.js"></script>
```

and after including both js

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   var currentTimezone = jstz.determine();
   var timezone = currentTimezone.name();
   alert(timezone);
});

</script>
```